# Destroy Function in Ruby On Rails does not work

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've used he rails engine to create a demo app. Everything works fine, except the "Destroy" function deos not do anything.
There is no error message.

Can anyone guess as to why nothing would happen, even though there is no error message?

The function (auto-created) is:

```
  def destroy
    @term = Term.find(params[:id])
    @term.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to terms_url }
      format.json { head :ok }
    end
  end
```

and the HTMl part is:

```
<td><%= link_to 'Destroy', term, confirm: 'Are you sure?', method: :delete %></td>
```

I dont even get the confirmation question.
Checked, and JavaScript is enabled.

Comment: Can you post the output or "rake routes" ?

Comment: Maybe you need to use `@term` instead of `term` in the HTML? (Or is this link created in a partial?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a pretty common question, sounds like you're not including the javascript that shows the confirmation and implements the delete method across all browsers that don't support it - did you include the rails javascript libraries?

Rails 3.1

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
```

Rails 3

```
<%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>
```

see [link_to delete url is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4423314/link-to-delete-url-is-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

I think your link_to signature is wrong.  Try:

```
<%= link_to 'Destroy', term, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %>
```

Comment: he's using Ruby 1.9.2 hash syntax. It's fine.

Comment: John- this guy is obviously new to StackOverflow. Don't vote down a simple mistake - just tell him what he did.