# Why the destroy/delete link dees not work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, destroy

I am stuck at Delete/Destroy. Any help would be appreciated!

I am using Ruby 2.0.0 and Rails 3.2.6 on Mac 10.8.3 with Postgres.

This is the delete link which supposed to work:

```
<%= link_to 'Destroy', @product, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
```

But when I click on the Destroy link it directs me to the user's profile. I don't get any confirmation window and no action is done (delete). It seems it is just stayed at the same page. I am using Firefox but in IE and Chrome are the same.

This is what I have:

1. the gem "jquery-rails" is installed
2. applications.js (from app/assets/javascripts) has these lines:

   ```
   //= require jquery
   //= require jquery_ujs
   //= require_tree .
   ```
3. application.html.erb (from app/views/layouts) has these lines:

   ```
   <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
   <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
   ```

   In view source I see:

   ```
   <script src="/assets/application.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <meta content="authenticity_token" name="csrf-param" />
   <meta content="MVlJi+WJE1cwWoHnBrpRWIa13gqio0iPT3IL6kpQYdE=" name="csrf-token" />
   ```
4. in products_controllers.rb (from app/controllers) I have:

   ```
   def destroy
       @product = Product.where(:id => params[:id]).first
       @product.destroy

       respond_to do |format|
           format.html { redirect_to products_url }
           format.json { head :no_content}
       end
   end
   ```
5. in routes.rb (from config) I have:

   ```
   resources :products
   ```

What is wrong with that Destroy link?

On the same RoR project the Edit link works fine.

So, why the link doesn't work? Is it a Javascript problem or some other problem which I am not seeing?

And here is the server's log: (It seems the "delete" action does not been executed)

```
Started GET "/products/9" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-08-01 20:01:08 -0500
Processing by ProductsController#show as HTML
Parameters: {"id"=>"9"}
Product Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "products".* FROM "products" WHERE "products"."id" = 9 LIMIT 1
Rendered products/show.html.erb within layouts/application (0.5ms)
Completed 200 OK in 27ms (Views: 25.8ms | ActiveRecord: 0.1ms)
```

Comment: Search in browser console for `JavaScript` errors.

Comment: Try with `link_to 'Destroy', product_path(@product.id), method: :delete` and also take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4423314/link-to-delete-url-is-not-working

Comment: See your server's log.

Comment: Please provide some information about the error from the server log.

Comment: @MrYoshiji, hey, I tried this, but it does not work for me....:(

Comment: @cortex, hey, according to the log, it seems the "delete" does not executed.

Comment: Here is the server's log:  
Started GET "/products/9" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-08-01 20:01:08 -0500
Processing by ProductsController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"9"}
  Product Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "products".* FROM "products" WHERE "products"."id" = 9 LIMIT 1
  Rendered products/show.html.erb within layouts/application (0.5ms)
Completed 200 OK in 27ms (Views: 25.8ms | ActiveRecord: 0.1ms)

Comment: @MarkoHiel there is no error message here...I added the server log here...Thanks!

Comment: In order to debug, you could add a logging information like `pp "Destroy"`in your controller destroy action. In order to see if your request is passing that part of your app.

Answer (score 0):

One helpful way to handle path issues with Rails is to type "rake routes" in your console, in order to have a list of all the paths available to play with your ressources.

By declaring "resources :products" in your routes.rb file, "rake routes" will provide a list of Prefix/Verb/URI Pattern/Controller#Action for this particular resource. You will have something like:

```
Prefix  Verb   URI Pattern
product GET    /product/:id(.:format) product#show
        PATCH  /product/:id(.:format) product#update
        DELETE /product/:id(.:format) product#destroy
```

Take the word of the prefix column (**product**), add **_path** to this word (**product_path**), use the correct method (**DELETE**), pass the ids as parameters (in this case, you can just do **product_path(@product)**), and you're done. You will have :

```
<%= link_to "Delete", product_path(@product), method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" } %>
```

Comment: Hey, I tried rake routes, and I did get what you typed above, I changed my code into what you typed here...It did not work.....-_-||

Comment: Do I have to put the "<%= link_to "Delete", product_path(@product), method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" } %>" into a separate view? I put it in the show.html.erb right now...

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps (I'm just guessing, but one day I ran into a similar problem) if you design catalog or shop with a shopping cart based on the book Agile Web Development with Rails, the product model may contain a filter `before_destroy :ensure_not_referenced_by_any_line_item` that prevents the product from destroy in case if product listed in `LineItems`. If this is your case, you can clear list of LineItems in the `ProductsController` before destroying the product. Otherwise sorry.