# Delete database row in ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Can someone help me why the following two pieces of code do not yield the same 'result'?

Option 1

```
<%= button_to 'delete', {:controller => "articles", :action => 'destroy', :id => article.id}, 
  :confirm => "Are you sure you want to delete?", :method => :delete %>
```

Option 2

```
<%= link_to 'delete', {:controller => "articles", :action => 'destroy', :id => article.id}, 
  :confirm => "Are you sure you want to delete?", :method => :delete %>
```

Option 1 works. Option 2 for some reason calls the Show action in the controller. Funny thing is that Option 2 is used in the Ruby On Rails tutorial, which I was following....

As you can imagine I am a novice to ROR.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4423314/link-to-delete-url-is-not-working

Answer (score 3):

In order for `link_to` to work with the `delete` method, Rails needs the [unobtrusive scripting adapter for jQuery](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs).

- Make sure that your **Gemfile** has

  `gem 'jquery-rails'`
- Make sure that app/assets/javascripts/**application.js** has

  `//= require jquery`
  `//= require jquery_ujs`
- Make sure that your app/views/layouts/**application.html.erb** has

  `<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>`
  `<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>`

  inside the `head` tag. Remove the `'data-turbolinks-track' => true` section if you don't plan to use Turbolinks.

Answer (score 1):

Since browsers can't send natively extended set of HTTP verbs (DELETE, PUT, PATCH). Rails uses the `Rack::MethodOverride` middleware to fake it.

So when you do a POST request with the `_method = DELETE` param the request object that your Rails app receives has `request.method == 'DELETE'`.

Recommended reading:

- [Rails on Rack](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/rails_on_rack.html)
- [How do forms with PATCH, PUT, or DELETE methods work?](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#how-do-forms-with-patch-put-or-delete-methods-work-questionmark)

**`button_to`** creates a discrete form. So your "button" is really a form with hidden inputs.

```
<form action="articles/1" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">
  <input type="submit">This is the button you see</button>
</form>
```

Also Rails is pretty damn awesome so you can simply do:

```
<%= button_to 'delete', article, 
  confirm: "Are you sure you want to delete?", method: :delete %>
```

And it will figure out the route by itself as long as you follow the rails conventions.

**`link_to`** uses javascript to enhance a normal `<a>` element. Instead of the normal behavior the jQuery ujs driver creates a form like the above and submits it.

The most common reason that you get problems with `link_to` is that you don't have `jquery` and `jquery_ujs` included in your `application.js` or that you have a script error which is preventing it from doing its job. Check the browser console for errors.