# Rails using dot instead of slash in link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, slash

I know this question gets asked a lot

[Rails dot instead of slash in URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16264981/rails-dot-instead-of-slash-in-url)
[link_to delete url is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4423314/link-to-delete-url-is-not-working)
[Path helpers generate paths with dots instead of slashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5674116/path-helpers-generate-paths-with-dots-instead-of-slashes)

Just to show a few of them.

In all of them, a pluralization error seems to be the culprit. Yet when I try those solutions in my code, the issue still persists, which is why I am submitting this question.

So, in my main_pages_controller

```
  def console
   @article_list =  Article.all
  end
```

In routes

```
  resources :articles, only: [:create, :destroy, :edit]
```

In console.html.erb

```
 <% if (@article_list.any?) %>
   <% @article_list.each do |i| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= i.title %></td>
      <td><%= i.category %></td>
      <td><%= i.user.name %></td>
      <td><%= link_to "destroy", i, method: :delete,
                              data: { confirm: "You sure?" } %></td>
      <td>Edit</td>
     </tr>
 <% end %>

 <% end %>
```

This results in articles.X where x is the id of i.

If i replace i with articles_path(i), I get the same articles.x

If I replace i with article_path(i), I get article.x

If i replace i with articles_path(i.id) or article_path(i.id), I still get article(s).X

And if it matters, this is in articles_controller

```
def destroy
 Article.find(params[:id]).destroy
 redirect_to '/console'
end
```

What works to delete the articles is

```
 <td><a href="/articles/<%= i.id %>" data-method="delete" rel="nofollow" data-confirm="Are you sure?">Delete</a></td>
```

But I would like to understand what is happening so I can learn and be able to use link_to properly in the future.

Edit

So the above was for my article resource. With my user resource it works

Routes

```
resources :users,              only: [:create, :destroy, :edit]
```

main_pages_controller

```
def console
@user_list = User.all
 end
```

console.html.erb

```
<% if (@user_list.any?) %>
   <% @user_list.each do |i| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= i.name %></td>
        <td><%= i.email %></td>
        <td><%= link_to "destroy", i, method: :delete,
                              data: { confirm: "You sure?" } %></td>
        <td>Edit</td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>

    <% end %>
```

This is all copy and pasted from the article code, yet this gives me /users/X. So for comparison sake, users works, articles give me a dot.

EDIT

Since it was asked

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
 get 'sessions/new'

 get 'users/new'

 root             'main_pages#home'
 get 'home'      => 'main_pages#home'
 get 'author'    => 'main_pages#author'
 get 'article'   => 'main_pages#article'
 get 'console'   => 'main_pages#console'
 get    'login'   => 'sessions#new'
 post   'login'   => 'sessions#create'
 delete 'logout'  => 'sessions#destroy'
 resources :articles, only: [:create, :destroy, :edit]
 resources :users,              only: [:create, :destroy, :edit]

end
```

Comment: Please show your routes file. I assume you have singular resource.

Comment: @pascalbetz Okay, i threw the full routes up for you.

Comment: @user2303016 do you have an answer for your question? I also have this problem. All resoucres works fine but one has the same problem with the "." instead "/"