# ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Interfaces#index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to delete my interface,and it said

> No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"interfaces", :project_id=>#}, missing required keys: [:id].

Because I do not know which arguments should be put into `<%=link_to '删除', project_interface_path()%>`

I have tried many different arguments into a path.

#### interface_controller.rb

```
def destroy
  @interface = @project.interfaces.find(params[:project_id])
  redirect_to project_interfaces_path if @interface.destroy
end

def index
  @interfaces = Interface.all
  @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
end

def new
  @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
  @interface = Interface.new
end

def create
  @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
  @interface = @project.interfaces.new(interface_params)
  if @interface.save
    redirect_to project_interfaces_path
  else
    render :new
  end
end
```

#### interface/index.html.erb

```
<% @interfaces.each do |interface| %>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row">1</th>
    <td><%=interface.name %></td>
    <td><%=interface.desp %></td>
    <td><%=interface.method_type_id %></td>
    <td><%=interface.request_url %></td>
    <td><%=interface.request_eg %></td>
    <td><%=interface.response_eg %></td>
  </tr>
  <td><%= link_to '删除', project_interface_path(interface),method: :delete, data:{confirm:'确定要删除吗？'}, class: 'badge badge-dark' %></td>
```

#### This is my route file:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
  root "method_types#index"

  resources :method_types
  resources :field_types
  resources :projects do
    resources :interfaces
  end

end
```

Comment: Seems like your javascript is turned off, check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4423314/link-to-delete-url-is-not-working

Comment: Can you show me  the routes.rb file?

Comment: You have a typo on line 2 `@proeject`.

Comment: @PragyaSriharsh I have put routes file

Comment: @max i have corrected it, but it is not a main problem.

Comment: Do you see a confirmation dialogue box when you click delete?

Comment: @imechemi it just shows an error.

Comment: Based on workflow, you should see the confirmation dialogue first (which happens with the help of javascript) and then next would be the error you have found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<%= link_to '删除', project_interface_path(@project.id, interface.id),method: :delete, data:{confirm:'确定要删除吗？'}, class: 'badge badge-dark' %></td>
```

Comment: Your answer is correct and it has shown delete button. But after clicking delete button it shows undefined method `interfaces' for nil:NilClass

Comment: @HaoWen that is because you do not set `@project` in the destroy action like you do in say the new action ` @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])`

Comment: It means @project contain nil value. Debug and check the value of this. May be you  are not including :destroy in your callback that find the project_id and assigned to theinstance variable. Otherwise you can do this in destroy function too.

Comment: @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])  ...........

interface = @project.interfaces.find(params[:id])  ...........
interface.destroy